# Python's matplotlib import

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, anaconda, python-idle

On my working PC (Windows7, no internet connection) there are two Pythons: one is the main (C:\Python36-32) with IDLE. Another - freshly installed Anaconda (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) - just for scipy and matplotlib (IT guy thought it is the best option).

So, matplotlib works only if I run my scripts from cmd. But it is not comfortable. I prefer IDLE or any other modern environment.

But if I try use matplotlib in IDLE - I got an "No module named 'matplotlib'". I tried to edit sys.path and run:

```
sys.path.append("C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages").
```

It helps a little bit - I got new error "No module named 'matplotlib._path'". So, it looks like IDLE knows what is matplotlib now, but doesn't know it's functions.
Is there any way to connect IDLE with Anaconda's libraries? Maybe to append paths recursively?

Comment: The code you write, and in particular, any import statement, is executed by Python, not IDLE.  When you run `C:\Python36-32\python.exe -m idlelib` and enter `import xyz` in IDLE's Shell, the result should be the same as if you ran `C:Python36-32\python.exe` and enter the same `import xyz` in the standard shell.  The result you report is slightly puzzling, but I cannot say much without a full traceback and knowledge of the layout of a matplotlib install.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a good idea to mix the python distributions through the system path.

Python should ship with IDLE. So you can use the IDLE from the Anaconda distribution,

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3>python.exe Lib\idlelib\idle.py
```

Also note that Anaconda should also provide `Spyder`. This might be a nicer IDE.

Comment: `...> python.exe -m idlelib will start IDLE as well.  As implied, the important part is which python binary is invoked.